# sudo gradle command not found

Tags: linux, gradle

I installed gradle but can't use it from the `sudo` user.
I'll explain why do I need `sudo` using:

1. The jenkins job doesn't see gradle. It seems the jenkins execute commands from the `sudo`
2. When I started my tests manualy, using `gradle mytests` the server is freezes forever and I have no idea why (locally tests executed properly). This is the very hard issue that I can't resolve and I try to take my last chance - to use gradle with `sudo`. May be this is the reason, who know...

So, I'd set up PATH and GRADLE_HOME:

> echo $GRADLE_HOME 
> /opt/gradle/gradle-7.5

> $:~/temp$ echo $PATH 
> /opt/gradle/gradle7.5/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/opt/gradle/gradle-7.5/bin
> $:~/temp$ sudo echo $PATH
> /opt/gradle/gradle7.5/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/opt/gradle/gradle-7.5/bin

So, gradle folder contains in the both `echo $PATH` and `sudo echo $PATH` options (even two times, as I see now).
All answers in the other topics suggested to add gradle/bin folder to the PATH for sudo and it seems I did it and I do not know what I have to do in following

---

## My actions:

What I did to add possibility to call `gradle` with `sudo`:

- I have added `export PATH=$PATH:/opt/gradle/gradle-7.5/bin` to the `~/.bashrc`.
- Also I modified `/etc/environment` and added `/opt/gradle/gradle-7.5` to the string.
- rebooting server

---

## Instalation way:

```bash
#gradle:
wget https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-bin.zip
sudo mkdir /opt/gradle
sudo unzip -d /opt/gradle gradle-7.5-bin.zip
sudo nano /etc/profile.d/gradle.sh
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/gradle/gradle-7.5/bin
export GRADLE_HOME=/opt/gradle/gradle-7.5
source /etc/profile.d/gradle.sh

#jenkins
wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/jenkins.io.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo deb http://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list'
sudo apt update
sudo apt install jenkins

#jenkins launching:
sudo systemctl start jenkins
```

Additional info:

`$ groups ubuntu`:

> ubuntu : ubuntu adm dialout cdrom floppy sudo audio dip video plugdev
> lxd netdev docker jenkins

Jenkins I have started with `sudo`:

`sudo systemctl start jenkins`
Need to poind that `systemctl` not allowed without `sudo`

Comment: `sudo echo $PATH` - the shell substitutes the variable before the sudo happens, so that's still the non-sudo path. Try something like `sudo env | grep PATH`

Comment: Have you looked into using a [Gradle Wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) that would be checked in and live in your repository? Using `sudo` for non-admin tasks always gives me a weird feeling. Build tools should never need it.

Comment: Check the Jenkins configuration. Configure Jenkins Gradle and use its plugin to run the command. If you execute the command with the script then you should give the full path of the Gradle executable. Normally Jenkins runs with jenkins user. So you have to check configuration of gradle in that user.

Comment: @DhavalGajjar Yep, I exactly try to use Jenkins Gradle plugin and receive error "gradle not found". So I have to use "sudo /opt/gradle... /path/to/ptoject/tests". I'll update question with gradle configuration.

Comment: @Robert I agree with you. I also do not want to use `sudo`, but Jenkins use it!

Comment: @teapot418 You are right. `sudo env | grep PATH` soesn't contains path to gradle. But I did steps that I found in guides, you can see - I edited my question. How to correctly add path to the `sudo` PATH?

Comment: The purpose of `sudo` is to allow a regular user do administrative tasks on the computer without using the `root` account. Software development is not an administrative task. If you have a problem and you think that you solved it using `sudo`, now you have two problems. The first problem is still there but the second problem is that the files created by the applications that you run using `sudo` are owned by `root` and you need to use `sudo` again to remove them (or even to change them in some setups). Find the cause of the problem and fix it (you can use `sudo` for that).

Comment: _"The jenkins job doesn't see gradle"_ -- this seems to be a path problem. Login using the same user as the Jenkins daemon does and add the path to `gradle` into its `PATH` environment variable in `.profile` (or whatever is the file that the jenkins user runs to initialize). This is a good usage of `su` or `sudo`.

Comment: @axiac I use onli one single user - I execute all on the AWS server. I updated the question and added the `Installation` block. I have no idea how to install these all without `sudo`. Or do I mistake?

Comment: Do `sudo su jenkins` then check does gradle exists in the path. It seems the `jenkins` users do not find the `gradle` command or don't have access. Also `jenkins` user is not in the sudo group, sudo will not work.